# Which type of Clause is this?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> The environment was deficient in many resources, **among them salt, stone, and many other materials**.

Could you give me some more examples and explanation about this? Or Could you paraphrase it?

[Ancient Civilizations By Dr. Brian Fagan, Chris Scarre](https://books.google.com/books?id=xAy4CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22many%20vital%20resources,%20among%20them%20obsidian,%20salt,%20stone%20for%20grinding%20maize,%20and%20many%20luxury%20materials.%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI1ZTq5qrOAhXC7RQKHYbhAUsQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22many%20vital%20resources%2C%20among%20them%20obsidian%2C%20salt%2C%20stone%20for%20grinding%20maize%2C%20and%20many%20luxury%20materials.%20%22&f=false)

Comment: Unless I haven't had enough coffee, it's an _adjectival phrase_ that modifies _resources_. A _clause_ contains both a subject and a verb.

Comment: It can only be a preposition phrase since it's headed by the preposition "among". Its function in your sentence Is 'supplementary adjunct', though it doesn't fit in any of the usual semantic categories. Supplements are not modifiers, they simply refer to some other element (called the 'anchor') in the main clause. Here, the anchor is the noun phrase "many resources".

Comment: thank you both but Why no one answered this question?

Comment: I found another example in the book: "Many variables affected trade, among them the demand for goods." it seems that these authors like the way they're doing.  https://books.google.com/books?id=M8lwCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA299&dq=%22Many+ever-changing+variables+affected+ancient+trade,+among+them+the+demand+for+goods.+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj96qnbuKzOAhUGXhQKHU0FBNMQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Many%20ever-changing%20variables%20affected%20ancient%20trade%2C%20among%20them%20the%20demand%20for%20goods.%20%22&f=false

Comment: and this: "along with many other industries that were severely affected by the crisis, among them the steel industry" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Mexico

Comment: "many industries were affected— financial services among them"   https://books.google.com/books?id=5ceaRQNDsW8C&pg=PA37&dq=%22many+industries+were+affected%E2%80%94+financial+services+among+them%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTiYPnuazOAhVCsxQKHVbrAzMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22many%20industries%20were%20affected%E2%80%94%20financial%20services%20among%20them%22&f=false

Comment: @BillJ Of course. Insufficient coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase it:

> The environment was lacking many resources such as/some of which were salt, stone, and
>   many other materials.

So the meaning is that there weren't enough resources. Then, some of the missing resources were listed so as to give an example of what kind of resources were missing.

An example sentence I can think of:

> There are many vegetables in the salad, among them cucumbers,
>   tomatoes, carrots, etc.